# server service path in bat file

Tags: batch-file, service, batch-processing

I am writing a batch script that will stop, and start a services on one of my servers. 
In order to use this script remotely from my desktop, I assume I'd have to pass parameters for the server name and credentials. Can I do this? If so, what would an example be?

**idea one**

```
net stop <server name><credentials><service> 
net start <server name><credentials><service>
```

**idea two**

```
sc \\servername [user][password] net start service
sc \\servername [user][password] net start service
```

Pseudo code concepts above.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to start and stop services remotely.

```
 sc \\machine start <service>
 sc \\machine stop <service>
```

Run it as the user that has access to the server.